# Jenkins Active Choice param groovy script and static properties

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins Freestyle project with multiple Active Choice Parameters, the groovy scripts use some common constant values (also used at later build steps).
Example:

```
def constant1 = 'bla'
def constant2 = 'blub'
def constant3 = 'umpf'
def val1 = doSomething("$constant1", "$constant2")
return ["$val1", "$constant3"]
```

Right now these constant values are hard-coded and duplicated in the groovy scripts.
What is the best way of defining such constants?

Remarks:

- I thought about moving the groovy code into a scriptler "library" (not tried yet, no experiences yet)
- there will be multiple projects, mostly identical, except some constant values will be different
- there are other users and other projects on the same jenkins instance (ideally these shall not "see" my constants)
- Ideally the configuration of the constants can be done in the Jenkins GUI

Experimented with

- "inject env vars to build process" and "properties content"
- "prepare env for the run" and "properties content"

From the perspective of a GUI presentation that would be ideal, but seems not to apply to dynamic params phase yet (?)

I have seen solutions reading a props file (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570745/jenkins-active-choices-plugin-dynamically-populate-dropdown-with-properties-fil)) but ideally I would like to configure the values inside Jenkins.
System env vars are not an option.